# Adding key to javascript array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I used this vue.js library that requires an array in this format

```
    autocompleteItems: [
  {
    text: "Css"
  },
  {
    text: "Javascript"
  },
  {
    text: "Java"
  },
  {
    text: "Web Design"
  },
  {
    text: "Spring"
  }
],
```

However I need to get the items of that array from other array, how do I turn my "normal" array to this required format?

Comment: What you show *is* a normal array. It just happens to contain objects with a `text` property.

Comment: Use a map: `newArray = oldArray.map(text => {text})`

Comment: I didn't know this was called an array of objects, i suppose by normal array I meant array of strings, so like `array=['Css','Javascript','Java']` and I need to turn that into an array of obejcts with a `text` property

Comment: An array has a length and zero or more elements. No requirement for them to be any specific type. `['one', 2, { value: 'three'}]` is a valid array. [MDN: Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example that will give you an idea of how to add keys to your data

```js
array=["Css","Javascript","Java","Web Design","Spring"]

result=array.map(o => ({text:o}));
console.log(result)
```